Has anyone ever tried combining stoicism and Kant's moral philosophy (the Categorical Imperative)?
Forgive me if this is a stupid question. Especially since, as far as I am aware, there has been very little work done on stoicism since antiquity.
One of the principle ideas in stoicism is the isomorphism between nature and morality/ethics as well as the idead that "virtue is the only good". It seems to me that the categorical imperative could be a good supplement to this philosophy. As it could possibly represent a more analytic and rigours definition to that which can be condsiderd "good".

I can't answer your question directly, but it's worth pointing out that Stoicism is a virtue ethic while Kant's philosophy is a deontological ethic. These are really two different approaches to the same issue, and while one probably could integrate them, that would likely mean reimagining virtue in deontology terms or reimagine deontological principles in virtue terms. In a way it's like asking whether you can combine Euclidean coordinates and polar coordinates: the question doesn't quite make sense.

I think you are correct that there is in Kant's moral philosophy something reminiscent of the Stoic slogan "virtue is the only good". On the other hand there is no parallel in Kant to the link between morality and nature, which is also characteristic of Stoic philosophy. Nevertheless it could be possible to add Kantian-like arguments to Stoic moral philosophy.

According to Kant the good will is the only thing “good without limitation”.
To consider the concept "good" as a key concept for morality seems to be the only relation between the ethics of the stoicists and Kant.
Possibly you may search Stanford Online Encyclypedia about the characteristics of both types of ethics.
